# How to implement animation like closing movie credits in flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter, scrollview, transform

I want to make animated scrollview like closing movie credits in flutter. 
That's what i make.

[image]

That's what i want to make.

[image]

My code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AutoScrollPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AutoScrollPageState createState() => AutoScrollPageState();
}

class AutoScrollPageState extends State<AutoScrollPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool scroll = true;
  int speedFactor = 20;


  _scroll() {
    double maxExtent = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    double distanceDifference = maxExtent - _scrollController.offset;
    double durationDouble = distanceDifference / speedFactor;

    _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(seconds: durationDouble.toInt()),
        curve: Curves.linear);
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _scroll();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

    @override
  void dispose() {
    ///Don't forget to clean up resources when you are done using it
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String val = '''
BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.v 
BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.v 
BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.v 
BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.BUNCH OF TEXT HERE. BUNCH OF TEXT HERE.v 
''';
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          child: Text(
            val,
            maxLines: 1000,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 25.0),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: When my ScrollView reach to it's ends. It stop scrolling. 
But in Second video example text never stop scrolling. It's moving into space until become very tiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can use Transform widget for this.

Wrap your SingleChildScrollView with Transform Widget and use transform property to rotate that.

See the code below or See running example code at DartPade [ClosingMovieCredits](https://dartpad.dev/18e6a3217ff5b81636f15e5cb470fd8f)

```
Transform(
  transform: Matrix4.identity()
     ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002)
     ..rotateX(-0.7),
  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
     controller: _scrollController,
     child: Text(
        val,
        maxLines: 1000,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 25.0),
      ),
    )
  )
)
```